# Listbox Microsoft Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

How can I change the color of the selected item in the properties of the control? Currently, I have a listbox object which displays data from a query. When I click on a row it is highlighted black and the text becomes white. How can I change this black to another color.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible... directly. The selected color for the default ListBox control is the inverse of the Back Color property. This is true of the text color also. For example, try setting the Fore Color to Yellow and the Back Color to Blue. The resultant selected (a.k.a. highlighted) colors will be bluish text and yellow/orange backcolor.